# Running .net app when the specified version of .net is not installed

Tags: .net

I have a C# WPF application using .NET Framework version 4.6.2.  When you run the app on a system where an older version of .NET is installed, a message "This application required one of the following version of the .NET Framework..."

That's all fine and well, but I want to provide it with the .NET installer as in many cases the download pages are blocked.

Is there a way to do this?  For instance if the installer is in the same folder as the exe?

**EDIT:**
I should clarify something.  This app is a launcher that has three buttons to allow the user to run one of the installers.  This app does not get installed, the user just runs it instead of navigating into a sub-folder to run the specific installer manually.

Comment: have you tried publishing it with the Download Redist from internet ?

Comment: It's just a regular WPF application, I will have to Google what you suggest, I have never seen that before.

Comment: You have to build an installer or bootstrapping tool (in C++ for example, or PowerShell script) to verify .NET installation.